# Вызвать подфункцию в js

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal

Есть js функция модального окна внутри, которого есть такие функции как открыть, закрыть модальное окно. Теперь надо при нажатии на `<button class="choose">ok</button>` закрыть это окно т.е вызвать "подфунцию". Вот собственно код:

```
var Modal = (function() {
var open = function(m, div) { 
функция открытия}
 var close = function(event) {
функция закрытия}
}());

        Modal.init();
```

Comment: `Modal` - всегда undefined, так как из функции ничего не возвращается. Метод init Не определен даже внутри функции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так работать должно:

```js
var Modal = (function() {
  var init = (name) => { console.log(name) } 
  var open = (m, div) => { console.log('open') }
  var close = (event) => { console.log('close') }
  return {open, close, init};
})();

console.log(Modal.init('myName'));
```

Answer (score 1):

да както так делать надо, что вы изобретаете велосипеды ?

```js
var Modal = {
init: function(){console.log('init')},
open: function(){console.log('open')},
close: function(){console.log('close')}
};
Modal.init()
Modal.open();
Modal.close();
```